How do I tell if an event is completed?
How do I recognize which verbs show completion?

When I cut the grass I went home to drink something

Does it mean that after cutting I went home or is it a bad example that needs to be rephrased?

This sentence is not idiomatic. You could say "When I had cut the grass..." or "After I cut the grass..."

After I had cut the grass…

When I finished cutting...

Yes, it is a bad example that needs to be rephrased.
When does not indicate sequence or completion. Simple tenses do not do so either.
We use the perfect, the appropriate time phrase, and sometimes enlist other verbs to express those aspects.

After I cut the grass I sat down and had a beer.
After I had cut the grass I sat down and had a beer.
After cutting the grass I sat down and had a beer.
When I had finished cutting the grass I sat down and had a beer.

P.S. The order in which the two events appear in the sentence is irrelevant to their real-world temporal sequence:

I drank a beer after cutting the grass.
I drank a beer after I had cut the grass.
I drank a beer after I finished cutting the grass.
I drank a beer after I had finished cutting the grass.


what if you apply no change to my example? What is the meaning?

@marta It doesn't sound like a native speaker. Most likely a native speaker would say "When I finished cutting the grass..." or "After I cut the grass..."

The most natural way is to use an adverb such as "after"

After I cut the grass...

Or you can use a past perfect tense to indicate a completed action at given time.

When I'd cut the grass...

But the 'd is easily missed, so for clarity you can be explicit.  You can be more explicit with the word "finished", so combining these ideas

After I'd finished cutting the grass....


what if we leave my example with no change? What is the meaning there?

It's mostly just bad English.  It doesn't really mean much at all.  You can't go home at the same time as the grass gets cut, so it's contradictory. It's like a "colourless green idea" correct grammar, but meaningless.

I have one more example which I gave before. "When I fixed his car he paid me" and people stated it is fine. After the car starts working I get my money. Why is this interpretation possible if it isn't with my example with cutting grass?

Why not worry more about how to speak well, rather than how people would probably understand bad English in context? When an English learner is speaking we'll try our best to understand them.  We'll try to interpret in context and guess what you probably mean.  We'll use the context to understand your sentences.  That doesn't mean that they are "good English".  They are bad and should be rephrased.  Same with the cutting the grass example.  I'd probably interpret it as "when I'd finished cutting" from context. I'd forgive your bad English because you are a learner.  But learn to be better!

You repeatedly ask about badly phrased examples and get mixed responses because to understand bad English we have to read between the lines, and look at the context.  That is why people say different things. They are looking at the context.  But it is not "fine".  It is more or less understandable depending on the exact context.  And so with different contexts you get different degrees of interpretation.  But the key point is this is all bad English
